# broken start menu shortcut doesn't link to correct folder

Tags: shortcuts, start-menu

The start menu in windows 10 has shortcuts to the user folders on the left (ie music, documents, etc). Somehow the program CUEtools changed the Music shortcut to link to another folder, and i have no idea how to change it back, even through CUEtools. Any ideas?

Comment: Try running DISM / SFC.  The initial repairs can sometimes fix this kind of error.     .....     (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restore it back using Windows Explorer.

Open Explorer, right-click on Music, choose `properties`.

Find the tab Location, in there, press <kbd>restore defaults</kbd>

Apply and OK. It may ask you if you want to move the files back. Select yes.

The same can be done for all the other folders that have an icon and are usually located in your profile, such as My documents, My pictures, Desktop, etc...

Comment: So the music folder is now for some reason called "CONVERT" and the path is "C:\Users\*****\Music\CONVERT" when i click restore and apply it says "Can't move a child into a parent. The specified path is invalid"

Comment: Create a folder C:\Music, change it to C:\Music, move all files, then restore defaults.

Comment: Since it's already pointing to a child of the desired target, I would just edit the paths under: `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`. The entries you want to edit should be self-evident from the path, but the value name(s) are" `My Music` and possibly `{a0c69a99-21c8-4671-8703-7934162fcf1d}` (created when folder has been redired).

Comment: thanks all, i'm going to mark LPChips answer as the correct one, with the addendum that in addition to their advice, when i clicked 'apply' after 'restore defaults' i was asked if i wanted to move all the files contained within. when i clicked 'yes', i was getting the error message i mentioned above, but when i clicked 'no' it worked, and then i manually moved everything around. weird situation, in any case, thanks everyone